# Understanding Higher Order functions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, callback

I am currently reading Eloquent Javascript Chapter 5. They give the following example which is confusing the hell out of me.

```
function greaterThan(n) {
  return function(m) { return m > n; };
}
var greaterThan10 = greaterThan(10);
console.log(greaterThan10(11));
// → true
```

Can anyone break this down to me as simply as possible. I have huge trouble with callbacks. Especially when it comes to situations like these.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Higher-Order functions basically mean two things:

- Functions can take other functions as an argument/input
- Functions can **return** functions

This is what is meant by higher-order functions.

```
// this function takes a function as an argument
function myFunc(anotherFunc) {
  // executes and returns its result as the output which happens to be a function (myFunc)
  return anotherFunc();
}

// let's call myFunc with an anonymous function
myFunc(function() { 
 // this returns a function as you see
 return myFunc;
});
```

As for your example, it demonstrates higher-order functions by returning a function. It also demonstrates the notion of closure.

Closure is closing over a scoped variable, in this case the input argument n.

```
function greaterThan(n) {
  // n is closed over (embedded into and accessible within) the function returned below
  return function(m) { return m > n; };
}

// greatherThan10 reference points to the function returned by the greaterThan function
// with n set to 10
// Notice how greaterThan10 can reference the n variable and no-one else can
// this is a closure
var greaterThan10 = greaterThan(10);

console.log(greaterThan10(11));
// → true
```

Answer (score 7):

There's no "callback" involved here. What you've got with the "greaterThan" function is a function that returns another function.

So, you call the function:

```
var greaterThan10 = greaterThan(10);
```

Now the variable "greaterThan10" references the function returned by the "greaterThan" function invoked with `10` as the argument.

Then, you log the result of calling that function:

```
console.log(greaterThan10(11));
```

The function returned from "greaterThan" is invoked. It compares its parameter to the value of the parameter "n" passed when it was created. Because `11` is in fact greater than `10`, the function will return `true` and that's what'll be logged.